# What is the console command to undo expulsion from House Hlaalu?

Tags: cheats, the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

I accidentally got expelled from House Hlaalu in *The Elder Scrolls III: Morrowind*, and I'm not in a situation where I can easily make amends, so I would like to use the console to easily get out of this situation. What is the command to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For me, just running the following command in the console was enough to clear my expellation from House Hlaalu:

```
PCClearExpelled "Hlaalu"
```

After executing that House Hlaalu NPCs would talk to me like normal again.